# Integrating fractional part function

Tags: definite-integrals

If $f(x) = \min(\{x\},\{-x\})$, then find $$\displaystyle\int_{-100}^{100} f(x)\, {\rm d}x,$$ where $\{x\}$ denotes fractional part of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometrically, the plot of $f(x)$ on $[0, 1]$ is an isosceles right triangle with a hypothenuse (provided by the $x$ axis) equal to $1$. The area of such triangle is $1/4$.

$f(x)$ is periodic, and its period is $1$, so on $[-100, 100]$ the plot is just that triangle repeated 200 times. The cumulative area of those triangles is $200\cdot1/4 = 50$ which is the value of the definite integral.

Comment: The answer my book states is 50... Can you please reconfirm whether it is 100 or 50?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Oops my bad, arithmetic mistake.

Comment: Can you please explain how the triangle is isosceles?

Comment: $f(1-x)=min(\{1-x\},\{x-1\})=min(\{-x\},\{x\})=f(x)$. The graph is symmetric about the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I am unclear that how did you get the hypotenuse as 1? I thought base will be 1 as it is on [0,1] and for this interval f(x) will lie between 0 to 1 also. So, base and perpendicular should equal 1 and hypotenuse should equal sqrt(2) accordingly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Also, on [0,1] f(x) = x ... So, integral of f(x) from 0 to 1 will be 1/2 ... ? I know I am wrong somewhere but can you please help me realize the mistake?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali $f(0.7)=min(\{0.7\},\{-0.7\})=min(0.7,0.3)=0.3$

Comment: Woah, thanks a lot for patience and answers.

Answer (score 2):

as mniip said,there are almost 200 triangle in the [-100,100](as you can see from the graphic of function),square of one triangle equal to 1/4,so the answer will be 200*1/4=50
[image]

Comment: This answer made the graphical overview more clear to me. Thanks a lot..

Comment: you're welcome)

Answer (score 2):

$$ x=n+p\\x=\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor  +\begin{Bmatrix} 
x
\end{Bmatrix}$$ so we can write $\begin{Bmatrix} 
x
\end{Bmatrix}=x-\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor $

now note that f(x) is even function
$$f(-x)=min(\begin{Bmatrix} 
x
\end{Bmatrix}),\begin{Bmatrix} 
-x
\end{Bmatrix})=f(x)$$so $\int_{-100}^{100}f(x)=2\int_{0}^{100}dx=2*100\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$   $\space $It is because f(x)   is periodic function
[image]

$$\int_{-100}^{100}f(x) dx=200\int_{0}^{1} dx=200\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\boxed{50}$$
implicit ,it is a continuous function

Comment: Consider adding a `\cdot` because otherwise it looks like $200+\frac{1}{4}$